# JavaFX is there anyway to set the two colors of a selected treeview item using css

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

Is there any way to change the color of a selected `TreeView` item, instead of the default red and blue color that shows when a `TreeItem` is selected

[image: Screenshot of what I want to change]

Comment: Well that red line is already non-standard. What library are you using? Anyway, you probably just need to set a different background. For instance, with CSS it may look something like: `.tree-cell:selected { -fx-background-color: XXX; }`. If whatever library you're using uses a border for that red line you'll have to change the border color as well.

Comment: The red looks like -fx-border-left-color, but probably you already looked into that.

Comment: @Slaw That's correct, this is `JFXTreeView` from the `JFoenix` library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a standard java `TreeView`, I noticed that you're using `JFoenix`'s tree view `JFXTreeView`. You can change the color of this selection bar by applying:

```css
.tree-cell .selection-bar {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

To change that background color:

```css
.tree-cell:selected { 
    -fx-background-color: green; 
}
```

Comment: That works but what about the blue color background of the treeitem that appears when its clicked, how do i change that color

Comment: @TuleSimon you can change it using: `.tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}`